# React Input type="number" fields don't trigger onChange

Tags: reactjs, input, onchange

I have added `<input type="number" value={value} onChange={onChange}>` to a form and am checking the format of the input using a simplified onChange function as illustrated in the following component:

```
  export function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");

    const onChange = (event) => {
      console.log("onChange called", event.target.value);
      setValue(event.target.value);
    };

    return <input type="number" value={value} onChange={onChange} />;
 }
```

I would like restrict the value of the input to only be integers using validation in the onChange function.

However, before I can add the validation, I noticed that when a user enters a valid non-integer number input, such as `.`, `e` or `E`, the value of the input is not passed to the onChange function, and hence I'm not able to perform my validation.

Below is a codesandbox that can be used to reproduce the issue.

[image: Example]

What is the best way to add validation to an input field to ensure that the input is a whole number?

Comment: That's the whole purpose of putting `type='number'` as an attribute in your input field. HTML does that for you. The browser solves that for you. Why do you need to validate yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `e` is the only letter that's accepted in a number field because it allows for exponents. You could use `input type="text"` but it doesn't give you the browser's native up and down arrows that `type="number"` does. And the `pattern` attribute validates on submission but doesn't stop someone from typing the 'e' in the first place. In React you can use this to completely block the `'e'` key from being typed in a number input:

```
const [symbolsArr] = useState(["e", "E", "+", "-", "."]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="number"
        onKeyDown={e => symbolsArr.includes(e.key) && e.preventDefault()}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-smoke-euw6i?file=/src/App.js) Demo

Comment: when I add console.log on onKeyDown nothing happends

Comment: @AljohnYamaro copy codesandbox link and  see in demo. Everything work.

Comment: I recheck the demo and it works, apology I will update my down to upvote

Comment: can't update says "You last voted on this answer 8 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Comment: This doesn't work on copy paste, drag and drop etc.